# connecting multiple strings to path in python with slashes

Tags: python

I try to concatenate the following strings to a path

```
mr = "/mapr"
cn = "12.12.12"
lp = "/data/dir/"
vin = "var"
os.path.join(mr, cn, lp, vin)
```

leads to

```
'/data/dir/var'
```

To get to the desired outcome I need to remove the first forward slash in the variable lp

```
lp = "data/dir/"
os.path.join(mr, cn, lp, vin)

'/mapr/12.12.12/data/dir/var'
```

Is there a more elegant to do it as I do not want to parse all identifiers for a forwarding slash in the beginning?

Comment: if you concatenate what you have you'll get: ```"/mapr12.12.12/data/dir/var"```.

Comment: Why is your data formatted incorrectly (i.e. an absolute path instead of a relative path) in the first place? This problem should probably be fixed upstream.

Comment: The data I get is partly read out from configuration files which can be wrongly specified by users. It is of course possible to clean all read out data and remove the first / but i am looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: @StefanPapp: I'm not sure what you consider as "elegant" here -- if the input data is wrong, the processing to make it less wrong will usually have to look a little "wrong" too. You can always `var.lstrip(os.path.sep)` if certain of the paths are *never* allowed to be absolute. You'd probably do best erroring out on wrong input though, or at least throwing up some kind of warning so the input error isn't silently ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here depends on the context: How much power do you want to give your users? How much do you trust them to input something sensible? Is the result you want to get a relative path or an absolute path?

- **Option 1: Power to the users**

  Let the users do whatever they want and make it their own responsibility to get it right:

  ```
  result = os.path.join(mr, cn, lp, vin)
  # result: '/data/dir/var'
  ```

  This gives the users the maximum degree of control.
- **Option 2: Force everything to be relative**

  If you want to force every individual segment to be a relative path, there's no way around stripping any leading path separators.

  ```
  seps = r'\/'  # backslash for windows, slash for all platforms
  fragments = [part.strip(seps) for part in [mr, cn, lp, vin]]
  result = os.path.join(*fragments)
  # result: 'mapr/12.12.12/data/dir/var'
  ```

  If you need the result to be an absolute path, join it with your root directory:

  ```
  seps = r'\/'
  root = '/var/log'
  fragments = [part.strip(seps) for part in [mr, cn, lp, vin]]
  result = os.path.join(root, *fragments)
  # result: '/var/log/mapr/12.12.12/data/dir/var'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the whole thing about `os.path` to not specify any delimiters?

How about this?

```
import os

mr = "mapr"
cn = "12.12.12"
lp = ["data","dir"]
vin = "var"

os.path.join(mr, cn, *lp, vin)
```